# Regex match everything after each character

Tags: regex

I have below string pattern

step_User_Save_Action_Details

I want to make sure a capital letter follows after each underscore symbol.

**Example:**

```
step_User_Save_Action_Details - Should return true

step_User_save_Action_Details - Should return false
```

Tried with below pattern but seems to not working...

```
step[_[A-Z]*]
```

Comment: So, you just need to check? Why not use `_[a-z]` and if it is present, return *false*? What is your programming language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\bstep(?:_[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)+\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kC1sC5/1)

`(?:_[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)` makes sure that there is an uppercase letter right after underscore. `+` quantifier after this non-capturing group will let it match multiple of these underscores in the word.

`\b` is there to enforce word boundary before `step` and after last component.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to try something like this:

```
 ^step(_[A-Z][^_]*)*$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nC1lJ3/1)